# Is it true that Germans in World War 2 did not suffer punishment for refusing genocidal orders?

Tags: nazi-germany, holocaust

According to [Norman Naimark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norman_Naimark)'s interview on the [Lex Fridman Podcast (#248)](https://youtu.be/Vrz8YDl9CeA?t=3693s)

> One of the shocking things that I learned just a few years ago when studying the Holocaust is that you could pull out. In other words, **if they order police battalion to go shoot Jews, you didn't have to do it. You could pull out.** They never killed anybody. They never executed anybody. **They never even punished people** for saying, "no I'm not going to do that." So people are doing it voluntarily. [...] They don't pull out. - Norman Naimark

I doubt this claim. Is there evidence for this? Were Nazi's allowed to refuse genocidal orders?

Comment: I've read about a few cases where individuals refused to join those mass shootings, and in none of them were they severely punished for this. So as far as I can tell, the claim is accurate. I don't have sources at hand though to write a proper answer.

Comment: No repercussions *ever* for refusing direct orders? This claim doesn't exactly pass the smell test, does it?

Comment: @T.E.D., are you aware of the Posnan speech by Himmler? They *knew* not everybody would participate personally, even in the SS, and they *knew* that enough would do it for their purposes.

Comment: @o.m. - I'm quite proud of the fact that I'm not well acquainted with Himmler speeches. I do know people pretty well though, and it doesn't seem like a speech would have any relation whatsoever to how your martinet boss reacts when you refuse to do what they tell you to do.

Comment: "We of course understand that not all of you are comfortable eliminating the enemies of the German People and we will accommodate your consciences. So, anyone who doesn't want to follow the orders of the Fuhrer, raise your hand and we will...accommodate you."

Comment: One notes that the number who refused was small enough that the work could gone on without them.  Also that finding it difficult was only fitting for the naturally magnanimous German; the killers they recruited from the Slavs enjoyed it (they said).  And, in fact, the motive for moving from shooting to the gas chambers was to spare the men who found the work very onerous.

Comment: @MarkOlson, what you write sounds a bit flippant, but a German who wanted to shoot at armed Soviets rather than unarmed Jews could usually find a posting to do just that at the Eastern Front. See John's answer -- *completely* opting out of the war machine was impossible, but opting out of the Police Battalion shooting squads was possible.

Comment: Surely this is very specific to a _Police_ battalion as opposed to an army or SS unit where discipline would have been stricter and repercussions more serious?

Comment: I changed to Germans in WW2. Non-Germans under Nazi control could be killed for almost anything, including a refusal to participate in the murder of other civilians - though it obviously varied a great deal depending on the circumstances and nationalities involved. Germans, Nazi or not, didn't get killed for this alone per my answer.

Comment: As I understand (without any evidence), service in police or concentration camps was a huge fortune. They were mostly scared of displeasing their superiors and being sent to the front. I agree with @o.m. that they were able to volunteer to go to the front if they did not like killing prisoners.

Comment: @jhnlmn Mostly true, in fact concentration camp personnel not fulfilling their duties as expected could be sent to real combat or to fight armed partisans which was of course much dangerous. One example of this was Christian Wirth, who ended up being killed.

Comment: It is also pretty hard to believe that soldiers could refuse direct orders without consequences, *especially* in an army with such legendarily high discipline.  Even harder to believe for special branches like the SS.

Comment: Even if it was possible to suffer no official repercussions, like it was official policy, the men could not know what the consequences in war time of failing to participate along with their comrades -- I can think of two movies (Training Day and Casualties of War) where someone refusing to participate put his own life into jeopardy and this would naturally be a concern of anyone in a battalion who declined to do what everyone else was doing. I realize I am citing works of fiction but these movies showed what appear to be realistic behavior.

Comment: Do you desire an answer geared towards Germans or Nazis? Not every German in the 1940 was a Nazi. There was even people willing to pay with there lives for there anti-nazi views.

Comment: @NeilMeyer I'm more interested in Nazis. And by that I mean someone enlisted in the service of the Nazi military. I don't mean people coerced to serve in prison camps, or just someone who was ethnically German. There was obviously Polish and French collaborators that I would like to be included in this too. The statements in the conversation quoted would leave you to believe you could just walk away, and I agree with T.E.D. -- it doesn't pass the smell test. But this is an expert in the field of genocide and ethnic cleansing.

Comment: Yes, rommel refused to execute pow and was executed for it. Although it was soldiers he refused to kill not jews so I'm unclear if that is a disqualifier.

Comment: @NeilMeyer I would say so, since the conversation above is in the context of genocide, and killing one person is not a genocide.

Comment: There also was Fritz Guderian who was a famous tank general in Nazi Germany. Who was investigated but never charged with anything. His conduct was never considered to be anything unfitting a professional soldier.

Comment: As a side note: it's the [Posen speeches](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posen_speeches). Posen was the German name of the now again Polish city of Poznań at the time of Nazi occupation.

Comment: @jhnlmn "they were able to volunteer to go to the front if they did not like killing prisoners" What were the relative death rates of the two sets of postings?

Comment: @RBarryYoung "hard to believe that soldiers could refuse direct orders" - that depends on how one expresses his refusal. If he says "I refuse to obey orders", of course he will be executed, in any army, not only German. But if he says "I volunteer to go to the most dangerous post in Stalingrad", then he will be hailed as a hero.

Comment: Not just disobeying orders, which is an offence under any military system, but peer pressure. In Nazi Germany, would you want your comrades to "condemn" you as a "Jew-lover", or even worse, a closet Jew?

Comment: In a recent interview between Navy Officer Jocko Willink and US Admiral William H. McRaven, McRaven claims to have had a decades long career without ever remembering 'giving an order'. Point being that the magic phrase "that is an order" is not necessary in a sufficiently well run organisation.

They are extremely different to Nazi Germany committing genocide and I can't offer an expert opinion on your question in particular, but it's an interesting tidbit.

Answer (score 63):

This matter is entangled with one of the disputes within Holocaust studies, although it isn't the point of the dispute. That began with [Christopher Browning's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christopher_Browning) book *Ordinary Men* (1992), which is a detailed study of the German [Reserve Police Battalion 101](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reserve_Police_Battalion_101). Browning concludes from his detailed study that the middle-aged men who made up this unit mostly killed due to peer pressure and obedience to orders, but that they could get out of participating in massacres, although few did. To quote Wikipedia:

> The commander of the unit once gave his men the choice of opting out if they found it too hard, and fewer than 12 men opted out in a battalion of 500. Browning provides evidence to support the notion that not all these men were hateful anti-Semites. He includes the testimony of men who say they begged to be released from this work and to be placed elsewhere. In one instance, two fathers claimed that they could not kill children and thus asked to be given other work. Browning also tells of a man who demanded his release, obtained it, and was promoted once he returned to Germany.

[Daniel Goldhagen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daniel_Goldhagen) is another historian, who has written about Browning's work, studying the same unit, and claiming that Browning has misunderstood the motivations of its members. However, he [agrees with Browning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hitler%27s_Willing_Executioners#The_Evil_of_Banality) that members of that police battalion could avoid taking part in killings.

This does not demonstrate that *all* (para-)military personnel could refuse genocidal orders, but it does show that *some* of them did manage to avoid obeying them. In an armed service, outright refusing orders as a subordinate is usually totally illegal, but finding ways to avoid obeying them or to be exempted is far more practical. I suspect that Naimark may have over-emphasised his point, as is quite easy in unscripted speech. There is [plenty of evidence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extermination_camp#Extermination_procedure) that Nazis who were quite willing to execute thousands of people nonetheless experienced severe psychological damage from it. Quite a few went mad, or killed themselves.

The Nazis introduced gas chambers because they were trying to reduce the effects of the killings on their men. A unit commander, operating the ghastly parody of leadership that was common among Nazis, might well exempt men who were unwilling, so as to have them available for other tasks later. He might also consider the wisdom of pushing armed troops beyond their limits: he'll die if they shoot him.

Nazi Germany did not recognise any general right of conscientious objection. Members of Battalion 101 who opted out of massacres would still be expected to do all their other work and support the war in general. Anyone who refused to serve the Nazi state at all would have been treated like the [Jehovah's Witnesses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persecution_of_Jehovah%27s_Witnesses_in_Nazi_Germany) of Germany, half of who went to concentration camps between 1933 and 1945 after refusing to perform military service, join Nazi organizations, or give allegiance to the Hitler regime.

Things changed in the final weeks of the war. At that point, flying courts martial roamed German controlled areas, seeking out traces of defeatism and executing anyone they felt showed it. At that time, disobeying orders to massacre people would have been very dangerous, and desertion would be the best course of action.

Comment: This reads as if it does not answer the question, which is about "refuse", not "avoid", as it is phrased here. It's not about "motivation" of 'eager (volunteering?) units' but as I read it about direct disobedience within military contexts (or semi; like SS, but Q isn't terribly clear, perhaps too sweeping anyway))? // What is "the controversy" here? That one historian faction might claim 'all orders were to be followed, or else, sure as hell' was surely happening, while another one might claim 'everyone would(/or did?) have had a choice not to, but did so willingly nonetheless'?

Comment: @LаngLаngС, there is a shift in emphasis between the quote and the question by the OP. This one covers the situation of the Police Battalions explicitly mentioned in the quote. The "controversy" is that Evan finds the quote hard to believe, while there is good evidence for the specific case to find it truthful.

Comment: @LangLangC: is this better?

Comment: As explained in comments, those refusing to shoot civilians would quickly find "employment" at the front. Only potential exemption would be criminals (Dirlewanger Brigade for example), and they would end up being incarcerated themselves.

Comment: being offered an opt-out is not the same as refusing orders...

Comment: what is the "ghastly parody of leadership" common among Nazis you write of? (is it worth  a separate question?)

Comment: Shaken by the sentence about the fathers asking to be relieved of murdering children, I searched for the original.  The PDF of Browning’s book is easily found online.  The full quote seems of interest for this question (emphasis mine) : "Two policemen made the mistake of approaching […] Wohlauf instead of Kammer.  They pleaded that they too were fathers with children and could not continue.  **Wohlauf curtly refused them, indicating that they could lie down alongside the victims.**  At the midday pause, however, Kammer relieved not only these two men but a number of other older men as well."

Comment: @bertieb: By "ghastly parody" I meant a leader showing concern for the men he was leading in appalling crimes, with none whatsoever for the victims. The awareness that the acts were both criminal and inhuman, as shown by their effects on the perpetrators, but no trace of reconsideration of his position or actions.

Answer (score 14):

Yes, it is true. To the extent that one can prove a negative, we know that Germans were not killed if they disobeyed orders to kill Jewish civilians.

See [this exchange between Daniel J. Goldhagen and Christopher R. Browning](https://www.ushmm.org/m/pdfs/Publication_OP_1996-01.pdf). In his presentation on his book *Hitler's Willing Executioners*, Goldhagen states (per p. 17 of the PDF):

> The perpetrators were not coerced to kill.  Never in the history of the Holocaust was a German ever killed, sent to concentration camp, jailed, or punished in any serious way for refusing to kill Jews.  It never happened.  Moreover, in many units officers announced to their men that they did not have to kill, and in at least nine police battalions the men had been informed that they did not have to kill.  There is similar evidence for the some of the *Einsatzkommandos*.  There is also evidence that Himmler himself issue orders allowing those who were not up to the killing to be excused from it.

Browning, like his opponent, points out their disagreement on virtually every aspect of the subject which academics could disagree about. However, he goes out of his way to affirm their agreement on this point, and helpfully provides an example unrelated to reserve battalion 101 by quoting from Nechama Tec's book *In the Lion’s Den* (on p. 27 of the PDF):

> A selected few Germans, three out of thirteen, consistently abstained from becoming a part of all anti-Jewish expeditions.... No one seemed to bother them.  No one talked about their absences.  It was as if they had a right to abstain.

Edit: re smell test - in history noses are good, but sources are better. Sometimes what is counter-intuitive and outrageous to our notions of human nature is also the truth.

The non-coercion of participants is one of the most important and least appreciated aspects of the holocaust, notwithstanding that it's well-known among academics. For that reason I'd like to address some of the comments in my answer.

> No repercussions ever for refusing direct orders? This claim doesn't exactly pass the smell test, does it?

The quote in the question doesn't say that no-one ever faced repercussions for disobeying direct orders. It depends on what the orders were.

The quote in the question said

> If they order police battalion to go shoot Jews, you didn't have to do it. You could pull out. They never killed anybody. They never executed anybody. They never even punished people for saying, "no I'm not going to do that." So people are doing it voluntarily.

In other words Germans specifically weren't punished for disobeying orders to murder Jewish civilians. They *were* executed or imprisoned for some other challenges to Nazi authority.

In the PDF I linked, Browning described some of the things which did get people killed.

> Repression  was  real.    Bishop  Galen,  by  virtue  of  his  visibility  and  status,  barely
> survived  his  condemnation  of  euthanasia.    But  students  of  the  White  Rose,  who  passed  out  leaflets
> condemning the mass murders of the regime, were arrested, tortured, and beheaded.  Members of the killing
> units  could  individually  abstain  from  shooting,  but  those  who  encouraged  others  not  to  shoot  were
> courtmartialed for defeatism and subversion of morale.

As other comments pointed out, someone who refused to pull the trigger would just be replaced by someone who complied. It was quite a different thing to discourage *others* from obeying these orders.

> a German who wanted to shoot at armed Soviets rather than unarmed Jews could usually find a posting to do just that at the Eastern Front.

This is fairly plausible for some potential refusers, but there are a few problems with it.

1. Many of the people who were told to participate in the holocaust were not up to military service - such as those police officers in Reserve Battalion 101. At the very end of the war the Germans sent practically everybody to the front, regardless of their degree of participation in the genocide.
2. If you want to say that it happened, you need to find an example of someone who was sent to the front as a consequence of refusal to kill civilians. No-one has done that so far.
3. Soldiers on the Eastern Front, including non-SS soldiers in the Wehrmacht, were some of the most likely people to be involved in killing Jews and other civilians. Since they were already at the front, fear of being sent there clearly can't have been their motive for participating.

> Even if it was possible to suffer no official repercussions, like it was official policy, the men could not know what the consequences in war time of failing to participate along with their comrades -- I can think of two movies (Training Day and Casualties of War) where someone refusing to participate put his own life into jeopardy and this would naturally be a concern of anyone in a battalion who declined to do what everyone else was doing. I realize I am citing works of fiction but these movies showed what appear to be realistic behavior.

There is no doubt that Germans were under tremendous pressure to obey and conform. There was a general climate of fear which must have been influential. However, once you have seen or heard of someone who refused to kill and was not punished for it, you would have no reason to think that you would be punished for doing the same thing. According to Browning (Goldhagen disagrees with this one, FWIW), 'some  10-20%  of  the  reserve  policemen  refused  or  evaded  and
became “non-shooters”.' So it's not believable that a large number of perpetrators honestly thought they'd get killed for refusing to kill civilians.

Comment: Dietrich Bonehoffer was a famous abstaine. If you consider being sent to a death camp and executed as bothersome then that last para seems false. His sacrifice is also well documented in the Christian circles that he represented. Not many German of his era conducted themselves to such a high moral standard. Right to abstain maybe, but some at least paid for it with there lives.

Comment: Bonhoeffer was killed for trying to overthrow Hitler. That's a lot more serious than looking at your shoes and mumbling an excuse when someone's ordered you to do something you don't want to do.

Comment: @NeilMeyer The distinction between "not actively taking part in genocide" and "advocating against genocide" is relevant here. The claim here is that the former didn't get you punished. The latter often did.

Comment: I'm curious, having read neither the linked PDF nor the book, does Goldhagen provide evidence or documentation to back up his claim? (Not looking for a full dissertation, just a simple yes/no to know if it's credibly supported.)

Comment: As I said, how can he evidence that something *didn't* happen? His evidence is that there is no known case of someone being punished for this reason. Taking someone to court is a bureaucratic process that leaves a lot of documents and witnesses in its wake. If the motive for participating in the holocaust were fear of being killed for refusing, then people would have to *hear* that refusers were being killed, so it's not like it could have been happening secretly. And we also know about many things the Nazis tried to keep secret.

Comment: Re. your points 2 and 3, my impression is that massacres were usually not carried out by front-line troops. And the logical consequence for being unfit for behind-the-front tasks would be to be transferred to some other unit, one that is most likely not behind the front. But I admit that I do not have any sources for that.

Comment: I'm afraid you're mistaken. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myth_of_the_clean_Wehrmacht#Participation_in_the_Holocaust

Comment: @Ne Mo this may be nitpicking, but my after reading the German WP article carefully, my understanding is that the shooting at Babyn Yar was done by the SS and Wehrmacht units were "only" cordoning off the site and destroying evidence afterwards. My comment re. behind-the-front units was meant to include Sicherungstruppen, who were definitely part of the Wehrmacht and involved in war crimes but not front-line troops.

Comment: An example for someone being transferred (but to Germany rather than to the front) would be Klaus Hornig. He actually did suffer quite severe consequences for refusing to take part in executions, but being an officer his case was probably somewhat untypical: https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klaus_Hornig

Comment: @Jan That is only one incident. I wouldn't advise staking too much on the proposition that soldiers who shot at armed Russians were particularly unlikely to murder unarmed Jews.

Comment: @Jan re Hornig, a brief look at the article (TBC, I'm reading the english google translation) suggests that he was supposed to *give* orders to kill civilians, and not only did he not do it but was brave enough to shout about it as well. This is a far greater act of disobedience than 'excuse me Herr Oberst, I don't feel very well today'.

Comment: @Ne Mo you wrote that the threat of being sent to the front could have been no motivation for the murderers. My impression is that most of the murders happened behind the front. Given that "behind the front" might have been safer than "at the front", threatening to send someone to the front could indeed have been a motive. Do we have casualty statistics for police battailons?

Comment: Do you know that people fighting at the front were not also participants in murders of civilians behind the front? Do you know that soldiers at the front were not ordered to murder civilians in the course of fighting at the front? The front moved back and forth and would sometimes cross over villages where Jews and other typical victims of the Nazis were living.

Comment: @NeMo You are correct regarding Hornig. He was punished for encouraging his subordinates to also refuse the orders, and for disparaging the SS. The ''crime'' was Wehrkraftszersetzung, not refusing orders.

Comment: @Ne Mo That is absolutely possible. But that does not rule out that a) being in a police battallion was less dangerous than being at the front, and b) likelihood and frequency of taking part in crimes against humanity was much higher for police batallion members than for front-line soldiers.

Comment: That is certainly a point German historians are making again and again, or [in this case](https://www.auschwitz-prozess.de/zeugenaussagen/Hinrichsen-Kurt/), a German prosecutor. ("Nun, Sie sind schon mal an die Front abkommandiert worden. Das wurde ja nicht allgemein geschätzt und wurde doch vielfach als Nachteil verstanden"/"Well, it happened that they were transferred to the front. Most people did not like that and it was often considered a disadvantage") I admit that I was not able to find a specific case.

Comment: @Ne Mo FWIW, I also agree with yours and Arno's assessment of Hornig. I think his case is independent from whether being sent to the front was considered bad or not. But a) he has a name, b) his case is useful for giving a more complete picture.

Comment: Better translation two comments above: "Well, it sometimes happened ..." etc

Comment: Fair enough. For the avoidance of any doubt I don't subscribe to Goldhagen's monocausal (his word) explanation, that the Holocaust happened because there was something particularly evil about 1930s-40s Germans. To me it demonstrates that most people most of the time do what they're told, notwithstanding how cruel and foolish the orders are or how wise and humane they themselves are. People were under terrible pressure to participate - it doesn't excuse anyone but it does mean credit is due to those who refused. Even to quietly renege on orders to murder must have taken great courage.

Comment: Agree. I actually was not trying to excuse anybody. I think most people would not think evading front-line military service is particarly honorable, and it is certainly not an excuse for taking part in mass murder. The holocaust is, at least, a huge moral failure for those who "only carried out orders" (even if I cannot know if I would have acted better).